# iPhone application won't compile

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

There is error compiling on line 6 and 7. It says "Expected identifier or (". Can anybody please help me with this one?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BIDViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;
[self.nameField resignFirstResponder];
[self.numberField resignFirstResponder];
@end
```

Comment: Sorry but ... Please go get a good book on the language. If you say you know it ok (then fix the question title)

Answer (score 3):

Your calls to `resignFirstResponder` don't belong in the `@interface`. They should be called from the relevant method in your `@implementation` (e.g. from [`textFieldShouldReturn`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn%3a), from a `UITapGestureRecognizer` or `touchesBegan` elsewhere on the screen, or wherever).

Answer (score 1):

BIDViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BIDViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;
@end
```

BIDViewController.m:

```
#include "BIDViewController.h";

@implementation BIDViewController

- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender
{
    [self.nameField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.numberField resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't fire methods in your header file. They need to be inside a method in your implementation file. Header(.h) files is for declaring stuff to the compiler etc. and the implementation file(.m) is where the magic should happened.

Do something like this

Your header file..

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BIDViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *numberField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;

@end
```

And your implementation file (.m)

```
#import "BIDViewController.h"

@implementation BIDViewController

- (IBAction)someMethodOrAction:(id)sender {

[self.nameField resignFirstResponder];
[self.numberField resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```